# Creating an internal-only Docker overlay network with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, overlay

I'm building a range of intentionally vulnerable/infected machines for teaching cybersecurity. For obvious reasons, I'd like this docker network to be completely isolated from the host and unable to connect to the internet. Looking at the docker-compose documentation this should be possible to do with the "internal" config option https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#internal, "By default, Docker also connects a bridge network to it to provide external connectivity. If you want to create an externally isolated overlay network, you can set this option to true." However, I'm having trouble getting this to work in my docker-compose file.

The network section of my docker-compose file looks like this right now:

```
 31 networks:
 32     lab-net:
 33         driver: "overlay"
 34             - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
 35             - internal: true
```

When I run docker-compose build I get the following error:

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 33, column 9
expected <block end>, but found '<block sequence start>'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 34, column 13
```

Clearly I'm missing something, I'm just not sure what. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is invalid `yml` syntax, not even related to docker:

```yml
driver: "overlay"
  - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
  - internal: true
```

As it says in the error message:

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: ....
```

So try this for an internal network:

```yml
networks:
  lab-net:
    driver: overlay
    internal: true
```

You may also want to refer to a complete example in [docker compose v2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ipam) docs that uses the `subnet` option you have in your example. The example in docker docs:

```yml
ipam:
  driver: default
  config:
    - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
      ip_range: 172.28.5.0/24
      gateway: 172.28.5.254
      aux_addresses:
        host1: 172.28.1.5
        host2: 172.28.1.6
        host3: 172.28.1.7
  options:
    foo: bar
    baz: "0"
```

So to make the above internal only it may suffix to add the `internal: true`, maybe something like:

```yml
ipam:
  driver: default
  internal: true
  config:
    - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
      ip_range: 172.28.5.0/24
      gateway: 172.28.5.254
      aux_addresses:
        host1: 172.28.1.5
        host2: 172.28.1.6
        host3: 172.28.1.7
  options:
    foo: bar
    baz: "0"
```